# Eigenfunction of all Hecke operators

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $f$ be a cusp form in $S_{16}$. I want to show $f$ is an eigenfunction of all Hecke operators, i.e., $T_n(f)=\lambda_nf$.

I know Eisenstien series are eigenfunctions of all Hecke operators, and by the spectral theorem the cusp form $\Delta$ is also an eigenfunction of all Hecke operators. But in general the product of eigenfunctions is  not an eigenfunction.

Comment: In general the product of two eigenforms (additive convolution of the coefficients) doesn't have multiplicative coefficients (eigenform). What is the dimension of $S_{16}(SL_2(Z))$

Comment: In general because $M_k(\Gamma_1(N))$ is finite dimensional it suffices to use http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/ `M := ModularForms(Gamma1(4),16);Basis(M)`  to compute the first few coefficients of the eigenforms $f_j$ and find from the first few coefficients of $f$ the $c_j$ such that $f=\sum_j c_j f_j$ 
 http://www.lmfdb.org/knowledge/show/cmf.sturm_bound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S_{16}(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))= \Delta\  M_4(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))$$ is of dimension $1$